# SPI MISO-MOSI signal are the same on oscilloscope

Tags: stm32, spi

I try to read a memory cell from a chip with my stm32f103  uC. I send three bytes, one instruction then 2 address bytes. Watching this on a scope I get the MOSI signals back, not the same level, but attenuated. Is that normal? If something's wrong with my chip, should the MOSI signal reflect back on the MISO pin?

Comment: No - probably wrong connection or  short circuit

Comment: No, it should be ok. I realized it must be only crosstalk, since the signal on the MISO line is around a hundred mV. It seems I dont receive anything.

Comment: 100mV on the not floating pin is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send more than 3 bytes master generates the clock. To read something master needs to send dummy bytes.